# Does a 'Broken pipe' exception cancel my job?

Tags: apache-flink

Currently I am running a Flink program on a remote cluster of 4 machines using 144 TaskSlots. After running for around 30 minutes I received the following error:

> INFO 
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.web.JobManagerInfoServlet  - Info
>   server for jobmanager: Failed to write json updates for job
>   b2eaff8539c8c9b696826e69fb40ca14, because
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.RuntimeIOException:
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.UncheckedPrintWriter.setError(UncheckedPrintWriter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.UncheckedPrintWriter.write(UncheckedPrintWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.UncheckedPrintWriter.write(UncheckedPrintWriter.java:295)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.web.JobManagerInfoServlet.writeJsonUpdatesForJob(JobManagerInfoServlet.java:588)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.web.JobManagerInfoServlet.doGet(JobManagerInfoServlet.java:209)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:532)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:453)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:965)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:388)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:187)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:901)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:47)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:113)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:352)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:596)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:1048)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:425)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:489)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:436)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:905)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.AbstractGenerator.flush(AbstractGenerator.java:427)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.flush(HttpOutput.java:78)    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$Output.flush(HttpConnection.java:1139)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:159)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:86)     at
>   java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:154)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpWriter.write(HttpWriter.java:258)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpWriter.write(HttpWriter.java:107)    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.UncheckedPrintWriter.write(UncheckedPrintWriter.java:271)
>     ... 24 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe     at
>   sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:470)    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.flush(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:256)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:849)
>     ... 33 more

I know that `java.io.IOException: Broken pipe` means that the JobManager lost some kind of connection so I guess the whole job failed and I have to restart it. Although I think the process is not running anymore the WebInterface still lists it as running. Additionally the JobManager is still present when I use `jps` to identify my running processes on the cluster. So my question is if my job is lost and whether this error is happening randomly sometimes or whether my program caused it.

EDIT: My TaskManagers still send Heartbeats every few seconds and seem to be running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a problem of the `JobManagerInfoServlet`, Flink's web server, which cannot sent the latest JSON updates of the requested job to your browser because of the `java.io.IOException: Broken pipe at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)`. Thus, only the GET request to the server failed.

Such a failure should not affect the execution of the currently running Flink job. Simply refreshing your browser (with Flink's web UI) should send another GET request which then hopefully completes successfully.

Comment: I am not quite sure whether it is still running since the transformation which is executed at the moment should take several hours to complete. When I refresh the WebUI at port 8081 it still says the job is running but my log is not updated anymore (at least it did not receive more messages within the last 90 minutes).

Comment: You could go to a TaskManager node and check whether the cores have some load. Alternatively, you could add some logging statement to the work heavy operators. Or you could bump the Flink version and use the new Web UI which now shows metrics such as written and received bytes.

Comment: After checking the CPUs I found out that my processes are still running. Thank you very much for your help.